# Export multiple Django models into one file

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to export your objects from different models to a csv file?
I can add all the objects from a model one by one, but I need multiple objects from different models next to each other instead of under each other.

```
for doc_uren in DocentUren.objects.all().values_list('docent', 'periode', 'studiejaar', 'uren'):
    writer.writerow(doc_uren)
for data in PeriodeData.objects.all().values_list('studiejaar', 'periode_1', 'periode_2', 'periode_3', 'periode_4'):
    writer.writerow(data)
```

This results in the objects from DocentUren, with the objects from PeriodeData the line under the last objects from DocentUren.
I need it next to each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `'studiejaar'` is a foreign key that links both of your tables.

What you might be looking for in this case is `prefetch_related()`. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for more information.

It basically performs a query on each table and joins them.

An simple implementation example for your use case could look like this:

```py
DocentUren.objects.all().prefetch_related('studiejaar')
```

Besides that a "non-Django" solution would be to loop through both lists and join them manually or convert them to [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) [Dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join) and export them [to csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv).